# Check if a string starts with a number in range

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing

I have a string that can be of random length and I need to check if it satisfies the following conditions:

- starts with 4 digits
- the first 4 digits form a number in range 2221-2720 (credit card number)

Right now I have the following code:

```
var isCardNumber = function (myString)
{
    var num = parseInt(myString.substr(0, 4));
    if(num) {
        return num >= 2221 && num <= 2720;
    };
    return false;
};
```

Can this be done simpler/shorter? Probably with a regexp?

Comment: Possible with regex but what you have is much cleaner.

Comment: This is a question for [codereview.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted on [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Should be on [*code review*](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). PS The if block is entirely redundant: `return num >= 2221 && num <= 2720` as is the *return false* statement.

Comment: Obligatory [`parseInt` radix warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix).

Comment: @JamesThorpe—for what values do you expect the OP to fail, even if the value is treated as octal?

Comment: @RobG It should be fine in this context, but perhaps only by chance, not by design.  People may not be aware that `parseInt` even has an additional parameter, and it may bite unexpectedly at some future point so I think it's still worth pointing out.  Maybe in a couple of years it won't be necessary as browsers will (hopefully) have moved on enough by then, but for now, I still think it's worth noting the lack of a radix parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var isCardNumber = function ( cardNumber ) {
   var n = +cardNumber.substr( 0, 4 )
   return n && n > 2220 && n < 2721
}
```

Comment: The initial `n &&` is redundant as for any falsey value *n*, `n > 2220` will also return false.

Comment: Undoubtedly, it isn't required there, but I guess it would be faster than comparing n with number

Comment: I think the speed would be more or less the same (only testing will tell of course), since if the left hand expression is NaN then `<` immediately returns *undefined* and the expression returns false. I'm just commenting on the redundant operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex for your general culture. As other said, I would not recommend using it. You could do performance tests but I'd expect it to be slower than the integer comparison test.

```
^2(2[2-9]\d|[3-6]\d\d|7([0-1]\d|2[0-1]))
```

To construct this kind of regex you need to break your range into easily reprensentable strings ; 2221-2720 is :

- 2220 to 2299 (`22[2-9]\d`)
- 2300 to 2699 (`2[3-6]\d\d`)
- 2700 to 2719 (`27[0-1]\d`)
- 2720 to 2721 (`272[0-1]`)

Then you can factorise it as I did or just use it as is, with each fragment separated by a `|`.